# Finding how many times an event occur within a time period

Tags: php

I'm sorry if the title is confusing, I'll try to explain better.

Say an event occurs every n weeks.
When user inputs a chosen day, I want to calculate how many times this event occurs between now and the selected day. The event's dates are fixed (not affected by user).

I can find the number of event between two specific days, as such:

```
$eventstart = strtotime("2021-10-18");
$chosenday = strtotime("2021-12-24");                   /// let's imagine the user chose this day
$event = 0;

    for ($i=$eventstart; $i<=$chosenday; $i+=1209600)  /// for example : every two weeks
    {
        $event++;
    }

echo "The event occurs " . $event . " times.";
```

This works just fine except that the start date is the same as one of the event, and I need the start date to be "now" (while keeping the events' day fixed).

I've tried to put this code in between some "while" or "for" loops but as expected, doesn't work. Am I really supposed to have a time interval within another?

I hope that made sense, thank you in advance.

Comment: Regardless of what start date the user selects, you will have to start your calculations from the next day in which the event occurs. But since you haven't told us the rule for when this mysterious event happens, we can't help you with that. For example, does the event always occur on every other Monday? The 1st and 15th of the month? Something else?

Comment: `"the start date is the same as one of the event, and I need the start date to be "now" (while keeping the events' day fixed)."` - can you try to clarify what that actually means please as I'm struggling to get my head around that. Also - for the above what is the output that you expect?

Comment: @kmoser The event would happen every three weeks (so I can't just make a rule for it to count every 1st of the month).

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Sorry I wasn't very clear with the phrasing. 

For example, say the event happens on October 18th and every three weeks onwards.
The user inputs Christmas.
I'd like to find how many times the event happens between now and Christmas. (So October 18th, November 1st, November 22nd, etc till Christmas 24th)

Is it this clearer?

Comment: and what answer would you expect for the data given? 5 or 6 or other?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Yep the answer should be a number like 5 (if there have been 5 events between now and the selected day)

Comment: The above code does output 5 so what is the problem?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius The problem is that it starts counting from the day I've manually selected (one random event day I've picked) instead of counting from the current time.
So if one event happens on October 18th (and every three weeks onwards) but the current day is, say, October 19th, it would still count the event from October 18th.

So basically I would need the code to find the next event day starting from today. How do I make it know which days are event days (every 3 weeks) while counting from today's date?

Comment: I guess to summarize, I need two different starting dates: one that starts from today, and one that keeps track of the event's dates. But I don't know how to make them interact so resolve my problem.

Comment: If the event happens on October 18th, but today is October 19th, why would you count the event on October 18th if it doesn't fall between today (October 19th) and the end date (e.g. December 31st)?

Comment: @kmoser because I'm not quite sure how else to calculate the events' dates without manually writing them. Is there no way I can store the info for which days the events will fall on, AND only start the counter from now? Maybe I'm asking too much of the code and should just manually change the next event's day every time? (every 3 weeks isn't too bad I guess but I thought there'd be a way to not have to change it manually)

Comment: @Lyswenn It's still not clear *when* the event is supposed to start. Without that info, there's no way to calculate what days it falls on. Until you provide that magical starting date, there's no way for us to really help you any further.

Comment: @kmoser Event starts on October 13rd, and happens every three weeks. I'm sorry if I've been too vague/unhelpful with my responses.

Comment: @Lyswenn Ok, so to summarize: the event starts October 13 and repeats every 3 weeks. You want to count how many times it repeats between Date 1 (which could be now, but doesn't have to be) and Date 2 (some arbitrary date in the future). Is this correct?

Comment: @kmoser Date 1 always has to be present time, but yes, that's exactly it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the answer you need:

```php
define( 'EVENT_INTERVAL_DAYS', 21 ); // Every 3 weeks

$event_start = new DateTime("2021-10-13"); // When the repeating event starts

$range_start = new DateTime("today midnight"); // Important: must include midnight so time is 00:00:00!

$end = new DateTime("2021-12-31"); // End of range to test

$first_occurrence = clone($range_start);

// Determine how many days to move $first_occurrence forward to actual first occurrence of event:
$diff = $first_occurrence->diff($event_start)->format("%a") % EVENT_INTERVAL_DAYS;

// Move $first_occurrence forward to first instance of event:
$first_occurrence->add(new DateInterval('P' . $diff . 'D' ));

// Determine how many times event occurs between $first_occurrence and $end:
$diff_occurrences = ( $first_occurrence->diff($end)->format("%a") + 1 ) / EVENT_INTERVAL_DAYS;

// Determine number of occurrences:
$n = ceil( $diff_occurrences );

echo "Between " . $range_start->format('Y-m-d') . ' and ' . $end->format('Y-m-d') . ", event occurs $n time(s)\n";
```